# jest.UseFakeTimers() / jestjest.runAllTimers() don't work

Tags: reactjs, testing, usefaketimers

I've just started the topic of testing in react, I've been introduced to some aspects of how and why to test in React. Everything's been fine until I wanted to use jest.UseFakeTimers() and jest.runAllTimers() to test if component state changes after and rerenders the component after a second of delay.

Component:

```
function App() {
  const [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() =>{
    setTimeout(() => setCtr(1), 1000)
  }, [])
  return <div data-testid="timer">{ctr}</div>
}
```

Test:

```
it("should tick after one second to new value", () => {
  render(<App></App>);
  const timer = screen.getByTestId("timer");
  expect(timer.innerHTML).toBe("0");
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  expect(timer.innerHTML).toBe("1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. useFakeTimers() replaces global setTimeout() and other timer functions, so it must be called before your tests.
2. After the rendering you must call runAllTimers() to fast-forward the timers.
3. Both rendering and runAllTimers() must be wrapped in `act()`.

See the [example here](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#timers).